# Stopover in Heathrow, do I have to secure any kind of UK visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Philippine passport and a Schengen visa. My flight from Barcelona to Stuttgart will make a 10hr stopover at Heathrow. Do I have to apply for any kind of visa with UK?

Comment: with Barcelona-Stuttgart flights taking 2 hours, and only costing around 100 Euros, why would you fly via Heathrow?

Comment: Find a better flight. The train is faster than that!